# how to prevent database and shared preferences from being hacked

Tags: android, sql, encryption, sharedpreferences

I am developing a password manager application that stores your accounts and their passwords in a database and stores a password of the application in a shared preferences so that your accounts can not be reached by others

what is the best way to protect the data
suppose that I create a method to encrypt the data and create a method to decrypt it so that a normal user can read the data

if a device is rooted can the hacker move the application data to another device with the same application so that he can read the database even if is encrypted because the application in the another device has the decryption method

is there a back-door method so that the hacker remotely transfers the data to anther device and decrypts the data by the application itself

If the encryption method contains generating random encryption key and storing it within the password string as a next line (multi-Lines are not allowed in passwords) is this a safe way because the hacker hacks the totally password string which encludes the encryption key then decrypts it with the application

suppose that I create a separate encryption key....It should be stored somewhere permanently....But if the hacker can access it can he crack the encryption by the application itself? if yes can the encryption key stored somewhere where the user can not reach it

note: making the encryption key related to the IMEI of the device is not a solution because I intend to make the application sync data between devices so many devices may have access to the same account

Comment: You're trying to solve this in the wrong way.  Derive an encryption key from the users password and encrypt the data with that.  Without the users password, and if you do the encryption properly, it's impossible to access the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has root, they own everything.  From a fundamental perspective, they could pretend to be the user, your application would decrypt the content for them, and then they'd have the results.

Having the sensitive content be encrypted *using a master password as a base* means that it would be safe to some types of attacks -- but if the attacker can have a piece of software watch for that password entry they can still steal it.  It does protect against some parts though, since when the software is "cold" (i.e. the password isn't there or loaded) the protected data is safe (if the encryption is solid).

Comment: Can I make the application prevent from runing in rooted devices so that the hacker can not decrypt the data

Answer (score 0):

There's a external library which is very good to encrypt the Shared Pref dat that uses Facebook Conceal

[Hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk)